# Customise checkbox for forms

Tags: html, forms, css, checkbox

I am trying to style a checkbox. The below code was taken from another question on this site and seems to be what I am looking for. However, I am unclear on how when this is used in my form I can check if the box is checked or not-checked when the form posts. Can anyone help?

```css
    input[type=checkbox] {
      display: none;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] + label {
      background: #999;
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
      background: #0080FF;
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing" />
<label for="thing"></label>
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're asking, but it's exactly the same as before – the labels toggle the checkbox, the checkbox is simply "invisible" in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
   console.log($('#thing').prop('checked'))
   if ($('#thing').prop('checked')) {
     alert("checked");
   } else {
     alert("does not checked");
   }
   event.preventDefault();
 });
```

```css
    input[type=checkbox] {
      display: none;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] + label {
      background: #999;
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
      background: #0080FF;
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type='checkbox' id="thing" />
  <label for="thing"></label>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```